# Unable to access the object which is defined in the model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying to list a data which is presented in the database and i created a class ViewingGoals and implement its business logic in the class ViewingGoalsBusinessLayer codes are as like follows

ViewingGoals.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BusinessLayer
{
  public class ViewingGoals
    {
        public string Goal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewingGoalsBusinessLayer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using BusinessLayer;

namespace BusinessLayer
{
    public class ViewingGoalsBusinessLayer
    {
        public void ViewData(ViewingGoals viewgoal)
        {
            try
            {
                string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
                List<ViewingGoals> viewgoals = new List<ViewingGoals>();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ViewGoal", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        //ViewingGoals viewgoal = new ViewingGoals();
                        viewgoal.Goal = rdr["Goal"].ToString();
                        viewgoals.Add(viewgoal);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my controller code is :

ViewingGoalsController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BusinessLayer;

namespace AppraisalManagementSystemFinal.Controllers
{
    public class ViewingGoalsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ViewingGoals/

        public ActionResult ViewingGoals()
        {
            ViewingGoalsBusinessLayer viewinggoalsbusinessLayer = new ViewingGoalsBusinessLayer();
            List<ViewingGoals> viewgoals = viewinggoalsbusinessLayer.viewgoal.ToList();

            return View(viewgoals);
        }

    }
}
```

in that controller wen i am trying to access the object from the ViewingGoalBusinessLayer 
List viewgoals = viewinggoalsbusinessLayer.viewgoal.ToList(); i got error as doesnot contain a definition for viewgoal.

please help me to overcome it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `viewinggoalsbusinessLayer.viewgoal`, you are trying to access a viewgoal property from your viewinggoalsbusinessLayer object.
Problem is that you haven't defined such a property in that object !
Here is an updated part of your code

```
public class ViewingGoalsBusinessLayer
    {
        public List<ViewingGoals> ViewGoals;
        public void ViewData(ViewingGoals viewgoal)
        {
            try
            {
                string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
                Viewgoals = new List<ViewingGoals>();
                // Rest of code is unchanged ...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Next problem is that you'll need to initialize that list, and I'm not sure what your ViewData function is doing...

Comment: i first use the code "public IEnumerable<ViewingGoals> viewinggoals" instead of the viewdata function but" i got error in the get function" "its not retrun all path code" thats why i changed .. thanks for your answer and please tell me how to call these function on controller i am begginer at mvc so please me to overcome it @darkchico

Comment: Can you try updating your ViewData code by removing the ViewGoal parameter and the line using it ? And in the while loop, use `ViewingGoals viewingGoals = new ViewingGoals (); viewingGoals.Goal goal = rdr["Goal"].ToString(); Viewgoals.Add(viewingGoals);` And in the controller, call the function with `viewinggoalsbusinessLayer.ViewData();`  Maybe that we'll correspond to what you need, but the names you chose doesn't make it very clear :)

Comment: actually this is my actual code using System;
   public class ViewingGoalsBusinessLayer{public List<ViewingGoals>ViewGoals
{get{try{string Connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connectionstring"].ConnectionString;List<ViewingGoals> viewgoals = new List<ViewingGoals>();
\\ado.net code\\while (rdr.Read()){ViewingGoals viewgoal = new ViewingGoals();viewgoal.Goal = rdr["Goal"].ToString();viewgoals.Add(viewgoal);
and its showing error in the "get function" as all code in this path  doesn't return value . what is the actual problem i did in here ??? @darkchico

Comment: Can you repost it in another answer instead of the comments ? It's getting hard to read here